# Equality between two norms

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Is it possible to have the following equality? $\lVert u^2 \rVert_{L^1}=\lVert \widehat{u}\rVert_{L^\infty}^2$. What kind of conditions should we ask for the result? And how can we prove the result? Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: The 0 function works.

Comment: yes but it's not usefull

Comment: Well you need to be more specific. What constraints is on $u$

Comment: Precisely it's what I'm asking

Comment: You should reword the question to be "what constraints on $u$ guarantee the norm equality"

Comment: As far we know $u$ is well defined so $\widehat{u}$ exists. Maybe the equality $\lVert u \rVert_{L^1}=\lVert \widehat{u} \rVert_{L^\infty}$ is usefull, so we can suppose that $u>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if $\hat{u} \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, one can modify $u$ to satisfy the equality. I will provide justification below, but would like to note first that my answer is based off the $2 \pi$ definition of the Fourier transform. That is, I define the Fourier transform to be:
$$\hat{u}(\omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t) e^{-2 \pi i t \omega} \, dt$$

If $u^2 \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and so $\hat{u} \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ by the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ Fourier transform given by Plancherel's theorem. Now, suppose that $\hat{u}$ is also in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. Define a new function $u_a(t) := \sqrt{a} u(at)$ where $a > 0$. Note that $\|u_a^2\|_1 = \|u^2\|_1$ and that $\widehat{u_a}(\omega) = (1/\sqrt{a}) \hat{u}(\omega/a)$. Thus, we have $\|\widehat{u_a}\|_\infty^2 = \frac{1}{a} \|\hat{u}\|_\infty^2$. We can then force $\|\widehat{u_a}\|_\infty^2 = \|u_a^2\|_1 = \|u^2\|_1$ by letting $a = \|\hat{u}\|_\infty^2/\|u^2\|_1$, and $u_a$ will satisfy the desired equality.